# Nested condition word problem on boolean values and inequalities

Tags: conditional-statements, racket

(This code is written in Dr. Racket) I have to come up with a function which produces true for even numbers less than 4 or true for even numbers greater than 30 and false otherwise. This is my code:

```
(define (special-number n)
 (cond
  [(even?) n])
   cond [(< n 4) n]
        [(> n 30) n]
        [else false]))
```

For some reason, my code isn't working. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first condition is incorrect, if the number is even you're returning it immediately. And the second `cond` isn't working, you forgot to put it inside brackets. The problem is straightforward, we just need to write the statement in code, word by word:

```
(define (special-number n)
  (cond
    ; true for even numbers less than 4
    ((and (even? n) (< n 4)) true)
    ; true for even numbers greater than 30
    ((and (even? n) (> n 30)) true)
    ; false otherwise
    (else false)))
```

Comment: @Diamoniner12345 Did this post solve your question? if so, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left. Also worth reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).